# ejabberd: Difference between "disco_local_identity" and "disco_sm_identity"?

Tags: api, erlang, ejabberd

What is the difference between "disco_local_identity" and "disco_sm_identity" module API methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumble on the answer:

It seems that the methods with "*local*" in their name identifier are related to the IQs destined to the server itself (ejabberd) whilst the "*sm*" (Session Manager) tagged methods related to other IQs.

See [IQ handlers](http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/ejabberd_IQ_handlers/) for more info.